# Position a <div> that stays at the bottom

Tags: jquery, css

How do I position a `<div>` at the bottom of the page that will stay there even if I scroll a page? Can it be done with just CSS or do I need to use jQuery too?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gyExR/16/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put `position:fixed;`:

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/gyExR/17/

Comment: Note that `position: fixed` is not supported by IE 6 or by many mobile browsers (including Mobile Safari).

Answer (score 2):

You can used fixed positioning for your `div`:

```
div.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;   
    height: 100px;     
    /* etc. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: fixed` on your "footer" `div`, and add `padding-bottom: 50px` (the same height as your "footer" `div`)  to `body` so that none of the content is hidden when you scroll to the bottom:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/gyExR/19/

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 50px
}
div {
    position: fixed;
    ..
}
```

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/css-fixed