# Position a DIV at the bottom of the Webpage (jquerymobile)

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I need to put a banner at the bottom of each screen. The screen resolution might change, since it runs with jQueryMobile (iOS, Android, WP7...).

What CSS should I use to fix a DIV at the bottom of the screen using JQUERYMobile? Thanks!

Comment: This question has been asked may times.  Try the **search box** in the upper right hand corner, it may be faster than waiting for an answer here.

Comment: Ok sorry, I searched on google and I wasn't lucky. But here there already is an answer for this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392412/position-a-div-that-stays-at-the-bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that using `position:fixed` is the preferred route, however you can also try using `data-role:footer`. Normally `data-role:footer` is used for navigation through your site though.

Documentation: [jQuery Mobile Footer](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/toolbars/docs-footers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Note that this whole topic is still not working correctly in JQM 1.0, and the fixed header dynamic position (that adjusts only when you stop scrolling) is causing some user discomfort.

I hope it will be more integrated with the new position:fixed of iOS5, althought I doubt such a nice implementation will ever be available on Androids (yes it exists since 2.2 but works very jittery).

Personally I don't use footer/position:fixed in my web-apps, since they always scroll down I've found it a better user experience to add everything to the top header.

Answer (score 0):

In JQM 1.1 is finally works.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
```

data-position: makes the footer stay at the bottom
data-tap-toggle: makes that ugly tap transition go away.